# How to use the API to get the HDR capability of the monitor in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, display, monitor, hdr

I want to use API to get HDR capabilities of monitors like shown in windows settings like "Play streaming HDR Video" and "Use HDR", please give me a C# example.

It would be even better if you could additionally tell me how to toggle the HDR state of Windows using the API!

I tried to use WMI to get # Set WMI to query the Win32_DesktopMonitor class, but there is nothing I need.